# How To Trap when Autofilter returns nothing

Tags: excel, vba

I couldn't really figure out how to title this, but here's a bit more in depth description. I have created a VBA code which will filter an excel file based on certain Criteria, and then whatever "matches" that Criteria will be renamed in cell A (Whatever row it is) and my macro goes to the end of the Criteria and then to the left, and will change it to whatever it needs to be renamed to and then copy and paste all the way above.

The problem: As of right now, if there is nothing that fits that criteria the code makes my cursor or whatever go all the way to the bottom of the document and pastes the rename from the bottom of the spreadsheet alll the way to the top. This is obviously a big problem, that I feel has a simple solution.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance, this forum is awesome.

Update: I have also attached an example excel sheet which if you run through this code (F8 all the way through), you'll be able to see where and how the error occurs. Thanks in advance guys.

Here is the link to download my file (Dropbox): https://www.dropbox.com/s/bx4ogcsdbmmzs59/ExcelExample11.xlsm?m

UPDATE: I have currently edited the code to this: And most of the time it will not go to Else...why does it continue when the cell below the header column contains nothing? I'm very confused.

```
Range("M1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="=BCC*"
If Not Selection.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CLO"
Selection.Copy
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "'Subtype"
Else
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't download your code right now, but I am 99% sure you can fix the problem by taking a look at these two statements:

```
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
```

When the filter returns nothing, the second of these will take you all the way to the bottom of the spreadsheet. So right after this statement you need to test the row number - if your row number is greater than the rows used, you have "run off the end".

To start with you need to know what the last "valid row" in your spreadsheet is. Somewhere in your module (or in a new one) define a function `lastRowUsed` like this (note - you can't just use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` since that will return a number < last row if the first rows are blank. If that's never the case for you, you can simplify your life a little bit):

```
Option Explicit

Function lastRowUsed()
' returns last row used on Active Sheet
  Dim address As String
  Dim lastRow As String
  Dim ii As Integer

  ' address of range has form $A$2:$C$10
  address = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.address
  lastRow = ""

  ' start at the end and work back until you find a "$"
  For ii = Len(address) To 1 Step -1
    If Mid(address, ii, 1) = "$" Then Exit For
    lastRow = Mid(address, ii, 1) + lastRow
  Next ii

  lastRowUsed = Val(lastRow)

End Function
```

Once you have this function defined you can test whether you fell off the edge (right after the `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` above) with a simple

```
if Selection.Row > lastRowUsed Then Goto NothingFound
```

And at the bottom of your code you create a label

```
NothingFound:
  ' code you run when you had "nothing found"
```

Here you handle the case you wanted to trap.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You may choose to "accept" the answer (little check mark to left of solution) as a way to indicate this solved your problem. Others will see "problem solved" and will be more likely not spend time reading the question and answers. And others with a similar problem will be guided to a solution more quickly.

Comment: Hey Floris, I am currently running into a problem running this code. I have changed it tos omething like this and it doesn't work (See OP)

Comment: When you are in a cell with data, but there's no data immediately below you, then `.End(xlDown)` will _still_ go all the way to the bottom. Could that be your problem? You have to test for "no rows found" and "one row found" - maybe these are two separate tests you have to do.